# Scaling up a parent and move it so that the child object is at the 0,0,0 point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I feel like this is a noob question but, I can't seem to find an example anywhere. Basically, what I am doing is I have a root object at the zero point and whenever I click on one of its children I scale up the entire object a certain ratio. What I am trying to do next is take the center of the child object that the user clicked on and put it at the zero point but also keeping it in the same local position with the root object.

I thought it would be as simple as:

```
root.transform.position = root.transform.position - obj.transform.localPosition;
```

that seems to get it close but, it is not quite the zero point.

EDIT:

To Clarify I want to move the parent but, make it so that the child is at 0,0,0 world position whereas the parent was at the 0,0,0 point previously. Think of it like this:

You have a small car model, the user clicks on the door. The car scales up and the whole car moves so that the door is at the zero point, offset by the distance that the door is away from the center of the car.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What zero point? From your code, how do we know which object is the clicked one? This is not enough to help you.

Comment: you just need to resize the parent and keep te children in the localposition 0,0,0

Comment: @PassetCronUs Zero point is Vector3.zero. The root object is called root and the clicked object is called obj.

Comment: @Chopi I want to keep the children's same local position relative to their parent but, make it so that their world position is at 0,0,0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parent object itself is not a child of another entity, then simply set its world position to *minus* the child object's world position:

```
root.transform.position = -(child.transform.position);
```

The transformation from local to world position automatically takes into account the scaling.

Comment: This works for some of the children but, not all of them.

Comment: Example cases please?

Comment: Well I have one component that is 5 meters to the right and 1.3 meters up locally when it has a scale  of 1. However, it does not have a scale of one, it has a scale of roughly .05. Whenever I apply this to my root object it moves it to -5, -1.3,0. The problem is that the bounds of the root object is only 1 cubic unit in size when it is this small size.

Comment: Because the children don't have their scale's manipulated, it is only the parent's scale that has changed.

Comment: Ah yes apologies. But in that case `transform.position` should have taken care of the scaling, since it applies the parent object's transformation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand completly your question. Do you want to put the child on the 0,0,0 position of the parent or the screen position? or do you want to be moved with the scaling of the parent?

If you want the child to move to the cero coordinates of the parent:

```
child.transform.localePosition = new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

Where "child" is the object child inside the object you want to scale.

You can see an example of it [here](http://www.example.com/).

Comment: Alright, Initially the parent is at the 0,0,0 point. What I am trying to do is move the parent object, not the child. However, when I move the parent I want to make it so that the child's world position is at 0,0,0 but it's position relative to the parent is still the same.

Comment: Well you can aproach this in to way or just setting directly the world positions of the child to Vector3.zero  or :

`child.transform.position = parentLastPosition - root.transform.position ;`

Where "parentLastPosition" is the position of root before moved.